# Top horizontal menu issue Prestashop 1.6.1

Tags: module, prestashop-1.6

I've some problem with module - top horizontal menu in Prstashop 1.6.1. This issue appear under opera and chrome and only in category or product. Firefox works fine with it.

While scrolling, top menu start to flashing and it displays strange.

Could someone help me to figure out how to fix this issue??

[Site](https://revolight.pl/23-zarowki-led-e27)

Cheers

SH

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I've some problem with adding link. Here is a correct one [link](https://revolight.pl/23-zarowki-led-e27)

Comment: Hello, any suggestions??